# How can i share quote records to opportunity team members and give them 'read' access?

Tags: sharing

i created a quote in an opportunity. Now i want to share the quotes related to that opportunity with the related opportunity team members and i want to give them only read access.

Comment: What have you done so far? What specific technical difficulties did you encounter?

Comment: @FlorianHeer , i just need a way to share my opportunity related CPQ quotes with my Opportunity team members so that they can only have read access. Currently i am trying to create a flow which i will call it from a process builder but i am not sure if it will work. Do you have any other ideas?